# Mint: startx from tty loads X in chinese

Tags: linux-mint, x11, locale

OS: Linux Mint 14
Tty: tty/6

I am trying to start X using startx from tty/6. I do not have a .xinitrc in my home directory. X gets loaded but it loads everything in chinese. I am not sure where the locale is set. Can someone explain why does it happen?

```
$ echo $LANGUAGE 
zh_CN:en
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably setting this locale somewhere in the `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/environment` or `/etc/profle` or in a file in `/etc/profile.d`. Depending on the distribution, the way how the `$LANGUAGE` is set can differ.

Try this to find the file where your language is set:

```
grep zh_CN /etc/* /etc/profile.d/* /etc/bash/* ~/.*
```

if one of these files contains the setting, grep should show you

Comment: i found the LANG AND LANGUAGE set in ~/.pam_environment. Is it necessary to have both environment variables? Also where can I get valid list of values for these environment variables. I want the value for UK English. `LANGUAGE=zh_CN:en LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8`

Comment: to be honest i don't know what `~/.pam_environment` is. but i'm pretty convinced it's no problem if you change both settings of $LANGUAGE to en_US or en_UK

Comment: i have removed $LANGUAGE and changed LANG to `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`. this is also dependant on the locales package being installed.